# Extract the uptime value from "w" command output

Tags: linux, bash, shell, uptime

How can I get the value of `up` from below command on linux?

```
# w
 01:16:08 up 20:29,  1 user,  load average: 0.50, 0.34, 0.30
USER     TTY        LOGIN@   IDLE   JCPU   PCPU WHAT
root     pts/0     00:57    0.00s  0.11s  0.02s w

# w | grep up
 01:16:17 up 20:29,  1 user,  load average: 0.42, 0.33, 0.29
```

Comment: could pipe to `cut -d " " -f 3`

Comment: Are you sure you have to get this from the `w` command output? Maybe there's something in `/proc` with the information?

Comment: @Barmar: Good point: `cat /proc/uptime`, which outputs fractional seconds (1st field).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that the format of the uptime depends on whether it is less or more than 24 hours, the best I could come up with is a double `awk`:

```
$ w
 18:35:23 up 18 days, 9:08, 6 users,...
$ w | awk -F 'user|up ' 'NF > 1 {print $2}' \
    | awk -F ','       '{for(i = 1; i < NF; i++) {printf("%s ",$i)}} END{print ""}'
18 days   9:08
```

Comment: @Sweety It would be simpler to use the `/proc/uptime` method described in another answer.

Answer (score 4):

On **Linux**, the easiest way to get the **uptime in (fractional) *seconds*** is via the 1st field of `/proc/uptime` (see `man proc`):

```
$ cut -d ' ' -f1 /proc/uptime
350735.47
```

To format that number the same way that `w` and `uptime` do, using `awk`:

```
$ awk '{s=int($1);d=int(s/86400);h=int(s % 86400/3600);m=int(s % 3600 / 60);
       printf "%d days, %02d:%02d\n", d, h, m}' /proc/uptime
4 days, 01:25   # 4 days, 1 hour, and 25 minutes
```

---

To answer the question as asked - **parsing the output of `w`** (**or `uptime`**, whose output is the same as `w`'s 1st output line, which contains all the information of interest), which **also works on macOS/BSD**, with a granularity of *integral* seconds:

A `perl` solution:

<sup>`<(uptime)` is a Bash process substitution that provides `uptime`'s output as input to the `perl` command - see bottom.</sup>

```
$ perl -nle 'print for / up +((?:\d+ days?, +)?[^,]+)/' <(uptime)
4 days, 01:25
```

This assumes that `days` is the largest unit every displayed.

- `perl -nle` tells Perl to process the input line by line, without printing any output by default (`-n`), automatically stripping the trailing newline from each input line on input, and automatically appending one on output (`-l`); `-e` tells Perl to treat the next argument as the script (expression) to process.
- `print for /.../` tells Perl to output what each capture group `(...)` inside regex `/.../` captures.

  - `up +` matches literal `up`, preceded by (at least) one space and followed by 1 or more spaces (`+`)
  - `(?:\d+ days?, +)?` is a *non-capturing* subexpression - due to `?:` - that matches:

    - 1 or more digits (`\d+`)
    - followed by a single space
    - followed by literal `day`, optionally followed by a literal `s` (`s?`)
    - the trailing `?` makes the entire subexpression *optional*, given that a number-of-days part may or may not be present.
  - `[^,]+` matches 1 or more (`+`) subsequent characters up to, but not including a literal `,` (`[^,]`) - this is the `hh:mm` part.
  - The overall capture group - the outer `(...)` therefore captures the entire up-time expression - whether composed of `hh:mm` only, or preceded by `<n> day/s>` - and prints that.
- `<(uptime)` is a Bash [process substitution (`<(...)`)](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessSubstitution)
  that, loosely speaking, presents `uptime`'s output as a (temporary, self-deleting) file that `perl` can read via stdin.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this with gnu sed:

```
$ w |head -n1
 02:06:19 up  3:42,  1 user,  load average: 0.01, 0.05, 0.13

$ w |sed -r '1 s/.*up *(.*),.*user.*/\1/g;q'
3:42

$ echo "18:35:23 up 18 days, 9:08, 6 users,  load average: 0.09, 0.31, 0.41" \
|sed -r '1 s/.*up *(.*),.*user.*/\1/g;q'
18 days, 9:08
```

Comment: @DYZ Why not? As soon as the next field (1 user) is delimited by comma should catch it.

Comment: Because the days and hours are also separated by a comma: ` 18:35:23 up 18 days,  9:09,  6 users,...`